# ReactJS/Javascript/Graphql/React-apollo: passing query variables

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to figure out how to pass the input variables to a graphql query function to run a query and display the results.  Not sure if I am passing the variables correct when the button is clicked.  The getObjectQuery takes two variables startTime and endTime, both will be selected on the frontend by the user.

Parent Component:

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          startTime: '',//This will keep track of the time
          endTime:'',


        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

      }



      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.startTime);
        this.setState({
          startTime: new Date(document.getElementById("startTime").value).valueOf(),//getElementById is a jQuery method
          endTime: new Date(document.getElementById("endTime").value).valueOf()
        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({//Assign the inputvalues, which is the current state, to the variables after pressing the submit button
            startTime: this.state.startTime,
            endTime:this.state.endTime
          });
          console.log(this.state.startTime);
          console.log(this.state.endTime);
        });
      };

      render() {

        console.log(this.props.data);//This is where data is.
        return (
          <div className="Calendar">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <label>Start Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="startTime" step="1" />              



              <label>End Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="endTime" step="1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            </form>

            {<ElementList startTime={this.state.startTime} endTime={this.state.endTime}/>}
          </div>

        );
      }
};
export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
  { options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ variables: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                            endTime: ownProps.endTime
     } }) 
  } } )(Calendar);
```

Child Function

```
const ElementList = (props) => (
  <Query
    query={getObjectsQuery}
    variables={props.startTime, props.endTime}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error</p>;




          return (
            <Item.Group divided>
              {data.action.map(action =>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li>{action.action}</li>
                  <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                  <ul>
                  {action.object.map( (obj) => {
                    return (<li>{obj.filename}</li>)
                  })}
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}

              </Item.Group>


            );

        }}


  </Query>
);

export default ElementList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be that you're just passing your props in as variables. They need to be set to specific property names in order for your graphql resolvers to accept them.

```
variables={{start: props.startTime, end: props.endTime}}
```